# Fill std::unique_ptr afterwards

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, unique-ptr

I have a function that takes a pointer to a pointer, and fills in the value:

```
void GetSensor(Sensor **sensor);
```

Normally, I have to do this to create the sensor and free it:

```
Sensor *sensor;
GetSensor(&sensor);
// Do something with the sensor
delete sensor;
```

Now I would like to use an std::unique_ptr for the same task. I know I can do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Sensor> safe_sensor;
Sensor *sensor;
GetSensor(&sensor);
safe_sensor.reset(sensor);
// Do something with the sensor
// safe_sensor will free the sensor pointer
```

**Can I somehow avoid the step with the temporary sensor variable? Would this work?**

```
std::unique_ptr<Sensor> safe_sensor;
GetSensor(&safe_sensor.get());
// Do something with the sensor
// Will the free work correctly here?
```

Comment: `unique_ptr::get` returns a pointer, not a reference to a pointer

Comment: @Angew: Nope, was not intentional. Should be fixed

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You're right... I guess thats one of the problems.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest is to wrap your code into a function:

```
std::unique_ptr<Sensor> make_safe_sensor()
{
    Sensor *sensor;
    GetSensor(&sensor);
    return std::unique_ptr<Sensor>(sensor);
}
```

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't give access to the reference to its owning pointer.

Comment: Not really an answer to my question, since the temporary variable is still here... this solution requires even more code than the initial example...

Comment: To end the suspense I would stress the last line in the answer above - "std::unique_ptr doesn't give access to the reference to its owning pointer." i.e. the answer is "no, you cannot". If you like it more you can make yourself some undefined behaviour with the call: GetSensor(&(Sensor*&)((char*&)(safe_sensor))); relying that internally the first bytes of the unique_ptr are std::tuple<pointer, deleter> i.e the first member of the tuple is the pointer :D I would NEVER use that but it compiles and runs seemingly ok with simple Sensor struct

Comment: @JanRüegg While true that it is "more code", it is now safer code since you no longer use that unsafe `GetSensor` call directly, you always use this `make_safe_sensor` function instead.  Now, if you could change `GetSensor` so that it returns a `std::unique_ptr` instead of taking a double pointer, then you would be making even better improvements.